# XSL for-each node comparison

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an input xml:

```
<ResultSet1>
     <set uid="80301707"/>
     <set uid="80301703"/>
     <set uid="80301705"/>
</ResultSet1>

<ResultSet2>
     <set itemNumber="80301707">
        <item>item2</item>
     </set>
     <set itemNumber="80301703">
        <item>item2</item>
     </set>
</ResultSet2>
```

I need to compare `for-each` of `/ResultSet1/set@uid` with `for-each` of `/ResultSet2/set@itemNumber`. If match is found, then I would need to select the value of `/ResultSet2/set/item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed `<root/>` node for Input XML :)

```
<root>
  <ResultSet1>
    <set uid="80301707"/>
    <set uid="80301703"/>
    <set uid="80301705"/>
  </ResultSet1>

  <ResultSet2>
    <set itemNumber="80301707">
      <item>item1</item>
    </set>
    <set itemNumber="80301703">
      <item>item2</item>
    </set>
    <set itemNumber="80301704">
      <item>item3</item>
    </set>
  </ResultSet2>
</root>
```

XSLT Code:

```
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="ResultSet1">
      <xsl:for-each select="../ResultSet2/set[@itemNumber=//set/@uid]/item">
            <!--Do whatever you wish :) -->
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

For the current XSL code: this will be the output:

```
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
```

hope it helped :) 
lemme know if any queries

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a complete, push-style solution** (no `<xsl:for-each>` used):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="ResultSet2/set[@itemNumber = /*/ResultSet1/set/@uid]">
     <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <ResultSet1>
        <set uid="80301707"/>
        <set uid="80301703"/>
        <set uid="80301705"/>
    </ResultSet1>
    <ResultSet2>
        <set itemNumber="80301707">
            <item>item1</item>
        </set>
        <set itemNumber="80301703">
            <item>item2</item>
        </set>
        <set itemNumber="80301704">
            <item>item3</item>
        </set>
    </ResultSet2>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that a match is found where there is a node in set1 that matches a node in set2, then it is built into XPath. Cfr. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ResultSet2/set/item[../@itemNumber = /ResultSet1/set/@uid]">
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

I haven't tested it.

Comment: But my output is basically a for-each of ResultSet1. Hence if use this logic inside it ie.,

<xsl:for-each select="/ResultSet1">
<xsl:for-each select="../ResultSet2/set/item[../@itemNumber = /ResultSet1/set/@uid]">
...
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

I am getting concat of item ie., <>item2item2</>

Comment: Got it to work. Used a template and used the for-each and if within it.

Comment: Yes it could have been a `test` in a `xslt:if`. Didn't know the context.